# php remove html code from scraped html with out id/class

Tags: php

I need to remove this html code from the html I am scraping, but I cant target it with its id or class. I need to remove all instances of this on the html code.

```
<ul data-bfa="@l:Subbuzz-Share;">
    <!-- MORE CODES -- >
</ul>
```

Comment: What are you using for the web scrapping ? And what is the output format? Do you want to have your scrapped data as text or another type? And do  you need to remove <ul ....> and </ul> or just <ul ....> ?

Comment: thats basically the format, with <li> </li> inside. using dompdf cant target it with id or class.

Comment: If you have any hope of receiving a quality answer, you will need to edit your question.  Include in your update, a couple of sample inputs (a representation of the full text -- but keep it small), show the code that you have used to attempt to self-solve, what your expected output is.  Without this, you will only receive low-quality assistance from less informed volunteers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use str_replace or regex(regular expression) to do so

For this particular element let's use str_replace:

```
// let's variable that contains the html tag
$html = '
   <ul data-bfa="@l:Subbuzz-Share;">
    <!-- MORE CODES -- >
  </ul>
';

$html = str_replace('data-bfa="@l:Subbuzz-Share;"','',$html);
```

See for more: https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.str-replace.php

// And let's use regex, which you can use for many cases in lifetime

```
// let's variable that contains the html tag
$html = '
   <ul data-bfa="@l:Subbuzz-Share;">
    <!-- MORE CODES -- >
  </ul>
';

$html = preg_replace('data-bfa=".+"','',$html);

// or another way with regex
$html = preg_replace('data-.+=".+"','',$html);
```

See for more: https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.preg-replace.php
Also check tis site, which very usefull to try the regular expression: http://regexr.com/

**Edit:** To be more specific

To limit html tag type:

```
// this is for str_replace but not good idea for this kind of situations, and it may not work if it doesn't match exactly
$html = str_replace('<ul data-bfa="@l:Subbuzz-Share;">','<ul>',$html);

// this for preg_replace
$html = preg_replace('(<ul )data-.+=".+"','$1',$html);

// this for preg_replace as well
$html = preg_replace('(<ul .+) data-.+=".+"','$1',$html);
```

You may get confused, inorder to understand regex, what you need to do is studying regex :)

Comment: when there are other html codes outside <ul data-bfa="@l:Subbuzz-Share;"> </ul> it remove its aswell.

Comment: @Boy You will not get good/usable answers because you are asking a question with insufficient details.

Comment: I just edited my answer but, you may still have quastions to ask, if this is the case read last line :)